# Delete child SKSpriteNode

Tags: objective-c, iphone, sprite-kit, skspritenode

Basically I am trying to make it so that when the user hits a fuel tank the old tank disappears and a new one is spawned in a random location. Right now it's detecting the collision but I can't get rid of the child. It will just add a new fuel tank without getting rid of the old one.

What can I do to remove the old child and generate a new one? removefromparent and removeallchildren is not working(nslog shows "move" s I am definitely getting to that statement after a detected collision)

```
- (void) fuelGenerate {
    //make a fuel tank

    for (int j=1; j<2; j++) {
        SKSpriteNode *fuel = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"fuel.png"];

        fuel.position = CGPointMake(arc4random_uniform(self.frame.size.width), arc4random_uniform(self.frame.size.height));
        [fuel setScale:0.6];
        fuel.zPosition = 1;
        fuel.shadowCastBitMask = 1;

        fuel.name = @"fuelNode";
        fuel.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:fuel.frame.size];

        fuel.physicsBody.dynamic = FALSE;

        fuel.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = false;
        fuel.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
        fuel.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = fuelCategory;

        fuel.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = fuelCategory | fireCategory;
        fuel.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = fireCategory;


        if (FuelGen == 1) {

            [self addChild:fuel];

        } else if (FuelGen == 0) {

            NSLog(@"Move");

            [fuel removeFromParent];
            [self addChild:fuel];
            FuelGen == 1
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: There are a some logical issues with your code but before getting into that, what is FuelGen ?

Comment: just a system to figure out if a fueltank should be generated etc etc.. It works fine. I was just having issues with deleting the old child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some observations:

You your code inside of a loop which only runs once. Why are you doing that?

If you are creating an object, in your case a SKSpriteNode, and want to delete it later on, you will need to keep some kind of reference to it. There are several ways of doing which include creating a property or adding the object to an array.

Your IF statement in its current position does not make any sense. Your code is in the middle of creating a SKSpriteNode but your IF statement only ads the node if FuelGen == 1. IF NOT it tries to remove the node which by itself should throw an error because you have not yet added it.

Lastly, when you are using an IF - ELSE IF statement, you should have an ELSE at the end to catch anything else that did not trigger any of the previous IF statements.

---

To create a SKSpriteNode property add this code between your import(s) and @implementation.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) SKSpriteNode *mySprite;
```

Now you have a property.

To use a NSMutableArray you would do make the array a property and then do something like this:

```
SKSpriteNode *myNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteWith....
myNode.name = @"SomeUniqueName";
[self addChild:myNode];
[myArray addObject:myNode];
```

Now you have created a sprite and added to your array and have a reference to it.

Comment: All those variables have been taken care of in other methods.

Comment: how would I do this "There are several ways of doing which include creating a property or adding the object to an array."

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have a reference to the "old" fuel tank.  All your routine is doing is creating a new fuel sprite and adding it to "self" as a child.

You need to get a reference to the *old* fuel sprite and remove *that*.  In your code, the [fuel removeFromParent] is referring to the new fuel sprite that you just created in that code above, not the old fuel tank that you're wanting to remove.

The way you do this depends on your actual implementation; if you only have one fuel tank, you can just keep a reference to it, for instance.  If you have many, then a more sophisticated system will be required, such as storing them in an array, or setting up your messaging to pass in the fuel node to your code.  But either way, you'll never be able to remove the old fuel node unless you have a reference to it in your code.

Comment: how do I keep a reference to only one fuel tank? I would prefer to just move the one I have?

Comment: The easy thing to do would be to just have an instance variable that points to your one fuel tank. Create it once when setting up your scene and just hold on to a reference to it. Then, when you receive the event that indicates that it has been hit, just set the position of the tank to where you want it to be in its new location. On the next update cycle, it will be drawn in the new location. (If you don't understand how to do the above, you might consider doing a little learning online before proceeding too far with your game - a few more techniques under your belt will pay big dividends.)

Comment: More likely, though, you're eventually going to want a more sophisticated solution.  For instance, you may want the old fuel tank to be exploding or having some other "outtro" animation while the new tank "intro's" in to the scene.  Or you may want to have a level that has more than one tank.  A better solution is to write your code in such a way that it doesn't assume there is only one fuel tank, but if this is your first project, and you're okay with there only being one tank that "teleports" in a single frame, you'll be okay with just keeping a reference to your single tank.

Comment: I'm just doing this as a exercise to play around with sprite nodes really (and having some fun in the meantime haha). "have an instance variable that points to your one fuel tank. Create it once when setting up your scene and just hold on to a reference to it" How would I do this? Thank you for your help :)

Comment: See @sangony's response below for how to do it.